# PHP: Extracting specific data from text and putting them in a list

Tags: php

I'm having trouble writing the code necessary for extracting certain data from the text.
My text is structured something along the lines of this:

```
[class name]. [class name]. (class units). [class description]. [class instructors]
```

For example:

> 200A-200B. Civil Procedure. (3)
>   The principles of pleading under the code system and the federal rules; modern trial practice, including venue, process, the jury, sufficiency of evidence, instructions, verdicts, new trials, judgments; appellate procedure. 
>   Ms. Aldave, Mr. Louisell, Mr. Poche, Mr. Stolz, Mr. Vetter
>
> 201A-201B. Contracts. (4)
>   The law of contracts, dealing with the prob¬lems of formation, operation, and termination.
>   Mr. Eisenberg, Mr. Kessler, Mr. Laube, Mr. Weintraub

And then the list goes on, with more a thousand more of these.

I want to break down the different parts of these listings and put them in a list for each of them. For instance, I would want all the class numbers in a list, all the class names in a list, all the units in a list, all the class descriptions in a list, and all the instructors in a list.

How would I got about this? I just started coding in php, any recommended readings I should do? Thank you.

Comment: As a hint to get you started you could use the `strpos` and `substr` functions to find the fullstops and "slice up" the text in between. Another slightly more powerful (and complex) way would be to use regular expressions.

Comment: Where are you getting this data? Do you have control of the output?

Answer (score 1):

Does this suit your needs? (I didn't use dots as separators, instead I use #)

```
$strings = array();

$class_codes = array();
$class_names = array();
$class_units = array();
$class_descriptions = array();
$class_teachers = array();

$strings[] = "200A-200B#Civil Procedure#(3)#The principles of pleading under the code system and the federal rules; modern trial practice, including venue, process, the jury, sufficiency of evidence, instructions, verdicts, new trials, judgments; appellate procedure.#Ms. Aldave, Mr. Louisell, Mr. Poche, Mr. Stolz, Mr. Vetter";
$strings[] = "201A-201B#Contracts#(4)#The law of contracts, dealing with the problems of formation, operation, and termination.#Mr. Eisenberg, Mr. Kessler, Mr. Laube, Mr. Weintraub";

$total = count($strings);

for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++)
{
    $string_parts = explode("#", $strings[$i]);

    $class_codes[] = $string_parts[0];
    $class_names[] = $string_parts[1];
    $class_units[] = $string_parts[2];
    $class_descriptions[] = $string_parts[3];
    $class_teachers[] = $string_parts[4];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($class_codes);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each line of the file and apply regex to each line to get

```
//I am just constructing $lines array assuming you have all lines of the file 

$lines[0] = "200A-200B. Civil Procedure. (3) The principles of pleading under the code system and the federal rules;
modern trial practice, including venue, process, the jury, sufficiency of evidence, instructions, verdicts, new trials, judgments; appellate procedure. Ms. Aldave, Mr. Louisell, Mr. Poche, Mr. Stolz, Mr. Vetter";
$lines[1] = "201A-201B. Contracts. (4) The law of contracts, dealing with the prob¬lems of formation, operation, and termination. Mr. Eisenberg, Mr. Kessler, Mr. Laube, Mr. Weintraub";

$regex = '/(.*)\.\s*(.*)\.\s*\(([1-9]+)\)\s*([^\..]*)\.\s*(.*)\s*$/';
$data = array();
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    preg_match($regex, $line, $matches);
    if(isset($matches[1]) &&
       isset($matches[2]) &&
       isset($matches[3]) &&
       isset($matches[4]) &&
       isset($matches[5])
    )
    $data[] = array("class_code" => $matches[1],
                "class_name" => $matches[2],
                "class_unit" => $matches[3],
                "class_description" => $matches[4],
                "class_instructors" => $matches[5]
            );

}
```

If you var_dump above `$data` variable you will get following output:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'class_code' => string '200A-200B' (length=9)
      'class_name' => string 'Civil Procedure' (length=15)
      'class_unit' => string '3' (length=1)
      'class_description' => string 'The principles of pleading under the code system and the federal rules;
modern trial practice, including venue, process, the jury, sufficiency of evidence, instructions, verdicts, new trials, judgments; appellate procedure' (length=222)
      'class_instructors' => string 'Ms. Aldave, Mr. Louisell, Mr. Poche, Mr. Stolz, Mr. Vetter' (length=58)
  1 => 
    array
      'class_code' => string '201A-201B' (length=9)
      'class_name' => string 'Contracts' (length=9)
      'class_unit' => string '4' (length=1)
      'class_description' => string 'The law of contracts, dealing with the probÂ¬lems of formation, operation, and termination' (length=90)
      'class_instructors' => string 'Mr. Eisenberg, Mr. Kessler, Mr. Laube, Mr. Weintraub' (length=52)
```

I hope that's what you are looking for..